# Open/Save dialog in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, dialog, cross-browser

When the user clicks a link to download a PDF, it is supposed to display a Open/Save dialog box. This feature , am able to see in **IE** and **FF**. But **Chrome** , it directly opens a PDF. While googling for this issue, looks like this has been raised as a bug. Has this bug has been fixed in Chrome browser ? Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: As a user, as a client-side developer or as a server-side guy?

Comment: Serve your file with the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serve your file with the Content-Disposition: attachment header.